# How to split an array based on minimum row value using vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out how to take the following for loop that splits an array based on the index of the lowest value in the row and use vectorization.  I've looked at this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html) and have been trying to use the numpy.where function but currently unsuccessful.

For example if an array has *n* columns, then all the rows where *col[0]* has the lowest value are put in one array, all the rows where *col[1]* are put in another, etc.

Here's the code using a for loop.

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[ 0.  1.  3.]
                 [ 0.  1.  3.]
                 [ 0.  1.  3.]
                 [ 1.  0.  2.]
                 [ 1.  0.  2.]
                 [ 1.  0.  2.]
                 [ 3.  1.  0.]
                 [ 3.  1.  0.]
                 [ 3.  1.  0.]])

result_0 = []
result_1 = []
result_2 = []
for value in a:
    if value[0] <= value[1] and value[0] <= value[2]:
        result_0.append(value)
    elif value[1] <= value[0] and value[1] <= value[2]:
        result_1.append(value)
    else:
        result_2.append(value)

print(result_0)
>>[array([ 0.  1.  3.]), array([ 0.  1.  3.]), array([ 0.  1.  3.])]
print(result_1)
>>[array([ 1.  0.  2.]), array([ 1.  0.  2.]), array([ 1.  0.  2.])]
print(result_2)
>>[array([ 3.  1.  0.]), array([ 3.  1.  0.]), array([ 3.  1.  0.])]
```

Comment: What if the same row has the minimum for more than one col? That sample looks very simplistic.

Comment: That's a good point. Let me update it to use <=

Comment: Can you explain why you are creating a numpy array and then creating a list of arrays? Seems like you want to just extract a slice of the larger array into smaller arrays which meet the conditions. Is that right. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `argsort` to see where the lowest value in each row is:

```
>>> a.argsort(axis=1)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Note that wherever a row has `0`, that is the smallest column in that row.

Now you can build the results:

```
>>> sortidx = a.argsort(axis=1)
>>> [a[sortidx[:,i] == 0] for i in range(a.shape[1])]

[array([[ 0.,  1.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  3.]]),
 array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  2.]]),
 array([[ 3.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  1.,  0.]])]
```

So it is done with only a single loop over the columns, which will give a huge speedup if the number of rows is much larger than the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution since it relies on simple python loops and is not very efficient when you start dealing with large data sets but it should get you started.

The point is to create an array of "buckets" which store the data based on the depth of the lengthiest element. Then enumerate each element in `values`, selecting the smallest one and saving its offset which is subsequently appended to the correct results "bucket", for each `a`. Finally we print this out in the last loop.

**Solution using loops**:

```
import numpy
import pprint

# random data set
a = numpy.array([[0,  1,  3],
                 [0,  1,  3],
                 [0,  1,  3],
                 [1,  0,  2],
                 [1,  0,  2],
                 [1,  0,  2],
                 [3,  1,  0],
                 [3,  1,  0],
                 [3,  1,  0]])

# create a list of results as big as the depth of elements in an entry
results = list()
for l in range(max(len(i) for i in a)):
    results.append(list())
# don't do the following because all the references to the lists will be the same and you get dups:
# results = [[]]*max(len(i) for i in a)

for value in a:
    res_offset, _val = min(enumerate(value), key=lambda x: x[1])  # get the offset and min value
    results[res_offset].append(value)  # store the original Array obj in the correct "bucket"

# print for visualization
for c, r in enumerate(results):
    print("result_%s: %s" % (c, r))
```

Outputs:

> result_0: [array([0, 1, 3]), array([0, 1, 3]), array([0, 1, 3])]
>   result_1: [array([1, 0, 2]), array([1, 0, 2]), array([1, 0, 2])]
>   result_2: [array([3, 1, 0]), array([3, 1, 0]), array([3, 1, 0])]

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier way to do this. I hope that I am interpreting the OP correctly.

My sense is that the OP wants to create a slice of the larger array based upon some set of conditions.

Note that the code above to create the array does not seem to work--at least in python 3.5. I generated the array as follow.

```
 a = np.array([0., 1., 3., 0., 1., 3., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 2., 1., 0., 2.,1., 0., 2.,3., 1., 0.,3., 1., 0.,3., 1., 0.]).reshape([9,3])
```

Next, I sliced the original array into smaller arrays. `Numpy` has builtins to help with this.

```
 result_0 = a[np.logical_and(a[:,0] <= a[:,1],a[:,0] <= a[:,2])]
 result_1 = a[np.logical_and(a[:,1] <= a[:,0],a[:,1] <= a[:,2])]
 result_2 = a[np.logical_and(a[:,2] <= a[:,0],a[:,2] <= a[:,1])]
```

This will generate new `numpy` arrays that match the given conditions.

Note if the user wants to convert these individual rows into a list or arrays, he/she can just enter the following code to obtain the result.

```
 result_0 = [np.array(x) for x in result_0.tolist()]
 result_0 = [np.array(x) for x in result_1.tolist()]
 result_0 = [np.array(x) for x in result_2.tolist()]
```

This should generate the outcome requested in the OP.